# How to create virtual directory on Local IIS using MSBuild and properties of a project

Tags: visual-studio, iis, deployment, msbuild, virtual-directory

I have VS2017 project with predefined usage of Local IIS in properties.
[image]
I have a Project Url as http://localhost/MyProject.Name there and want to see it on IIS the same way under Default Web Site (localhost:80, nothing special)

Default Web Site

|-----> other files

|-----> web.config

|-----> MyProject.Name (as application)

------------|-----> web.config

To do this I build it via Visual Studio Ctrl+Shift+B, then VS deploys it to IIS (creates virtual directory automatically) and that  works fine.

But I have many of such projects, which are built via script using msBuild like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe""C:\Sources\SCgit\MySolution.sln" /t:MyProject_Name /p:Configuration=Debug /clp:ErrorsOnly /verbosity:minimal
```

from PowerShell  and it doesn't  create virtual directories when builds project automatically like via VS. That's what I want.

Is there any way to tell msbuild to create such virtual directories using default pre-defined params from properties of VS project MyProject.Name.proj ?

PS

1. I really can't find the correct question for google, because it always redirects me to topics with a wrong value.
2. change of web.configs is not a good way for me, because script is a local improvement of personal performance. I need to build about 20+ projects from 10 different solutions for local development

Comment: @LexLi while I use default values from properties of MyProject.Name.proj  and VS can do it during build, why should I design a new bicycle? Or how can I use project (or its properties) to create virtual path for site (without typing all virtual paths etc.) via PowerShell.

From that example:
      PS IIS:\> New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\DemoApp\DemoVirtualDir2' -type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath c:\test\virtualDirectory2

I have no possibility to type physicalPath  and other params and store in some config, that's why I was looking for ready to go solution via msbuild like in VS

Comment: @LexLi, your 2nd comment is already a personal attack. You even can't imagine what I know and what I don't. Instead of anwser ( "how to" or "not possible to" or even ignore, you post a useless workaround-hack and criticizes refinements. No, thanks.

Comment: did you find the way to do this?

Comment: @Forklift no. Looks like it's not possible

Comment: Dang it, 2021 and this would be so useful to figure out.